# anchor tag in header not working on other pages except the home page

Tags: pages, links, template-hierarchy

I have a anchor tag that wraps around my logo image that takes you back to the home page using the following

`<a href="<?php bloginfo('url'); ?>"><img src="<?php bloginfo('template_directory'); ?>/images/logo.png" alt="Good Morning Moon"/></a>`

It is inside my header.php file. On my home page which is a staid page set to custom template with the following code it works

```
<?php
/*
Template Name:Home Page
*/
?>
<?php get_header(); ?>

<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

However on any of my other pages which are using the default template which I assume is the index.php file I have setup based on looking at the http://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Hierarchy the anchor tag does not show up, my index.php file looks like so

```
<?php get_header(); ?>
<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

What could be causing this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code you're posting *should* work, as far as I can tell; however, you're using some outdated template tags.

Try replacing `bloginfo( 'url' )` with `echo home_url()`, and `bloginfo( 'template_directory' )` with `echo get_template_directory_uri()`, like so:

```
<a href="<?php echo home_url(); ?>">
    <img src="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri(); ?>/images/logo.png" alt="Good Morning Moon"/>
</a>
```

For more specific instruction, it would be very helpful to see the *full* code of the *actual* template/template-part files in question.

Comment: Thanks for the updated bloginfo params. I thought I read them directly from the codex I would expect that to be the best place to see the update ones. It is working now, I thought it wasn't because when I hovered over part of the image it didn't show a mouse over icon, but it does on another part probably need to add a height and width for it.

Comment: oh actually something was onto of it in css, so I added a z-index to the div.